# Rails cancancan uninitialized constant Ability::Dashboard Did you mean? DashboardHelper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

I've a little problem with cancancan. I'd like check user's rights to access at his profile and admin dashboard. I've follow a tutorial who explain how use cancancan but  I've this error on admin dashboard

> uninitialized constant Ability::Dashboard Did you mean? DashboardHelper

Dashboard is my profile controller. If I remove dashboard's check in ability the error disappear. 
I've tried to find a solution on internet but nothing has solved my problem

Thanks for your help

The code is on github

https://github.com/remibovin/cancancan_project

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: I've tried this load_and_authorize_resource :class => Dashboard. I read this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27504292/uninitialized-constant-ability-rails but I've already a file named ability. I've check name's controllers.

Comment: Please don't post code you've tried in the comments. You need to read the guidelines for posting. Posting just the error is not helpful. Edit your question and add the web console logs from when you make the request until the error including the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is there is no Dashboard class in your application.  I think the best way to go forward is in your Controller use:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  authorize_resource :class => false
  def index
  end
```

and you can authorize the controller with a symbol in your Ability.rb file like so:

```
can :manage, :dashboard, user_id: user.id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's work with little modifications. I've modify 

can :manage, :dashboard, user_id, user.id
in
can :manage, :dashboard, user_id: user.id

and I've delete

user ||= User.new

Because it's create a nil user if the user isn't connected.

Comment: Yes that all makes sense.  Changed my answer.

Comment: Great for the next one :)